# Install Cloud Foundry binary on raspberry (linux v 4.4)

Tags: linux, git, installation, cloud-foundry, predix

After installing `maven` and `git` I tried to install cloud foundry so while installing 32bit or 64 bit i am getting error:

> `cannot execute binary file: Exec format error`

while running `./quickstart.sh` it is asking for *username* and *password* and when I am filling *`predix`* account detail then it is giving error.

If there is any video to install `predix` on Raspberry It would be helpful

Comment: Don't hesitate to use proper formatting and to read [ask]. Where you following a given tutorial? this would be helpful.

Comment: Just out of curiosity: Why would you want to install the command line client on a raspberry pi? I guess predix is the GE version of the CF CLI? You would need this for managing your app and for development...

Comment: Yes ,perhaps it is needed

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you may be having one of a few issues:

- Installing Cloud Foundry CLI
- Signing into Predix using the CF CLI
- Setting up a Raspberry Pi to communicate with Predix Platform

It is not typical to do development work on the Pi itself.  For more guidance on setting up the Pi with Predix-- see this step-by-step guide: https://www.predix.io/resources/tutorials/journey.html#1750

If you are getting a login failure from the CF CLI running on your development host (laptop), you'll need to provide a few more details on the error you are seeing.  Make sure you can login to the web console with your email / password to insure you have a valid account: https://www.predix.io/console/

If you are having trouble installing the CF CLI, you will need to provide a few more details about what is not running.  If you can run `cf -version` and get a response it is likely you have already installed it successfully.

If you do have the CF CLI installed properly, and you do have a email/password to log into cloud foundry -- next verify you are talking to the correct API endpoint and do not have a proxy blocking you.

For Predix, the API endpoint is: https://api.system.aws-usw02-pr.ice.predix.io

Some firewalls may block access however, so check the proxy settings for your organization to make sure you are able to access it.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Sir First let me know how to install CF-CLI in raspberry pi because when I i am trying to install by either option i am getting "Exec format Error "

Comment: Sorry, I don't know of anybody that has attempted to do that and answer will depend on what os you installed.

Answer (score 0):

Like the other answers stated - most people don't want to install the CF CLI on a Raspberry Pi.  It's possibly, but not what most people do.

The quickstart.sh is intended to be run on your laptop, which configures Predix machine software and pushes the configured software over to the Pi.  At one point during the script, you'll need to enter a username / password to connect to the Pi.  This is not your Predix password, just your device password.  Default is pi / raspberry.